Montel's Theorem corollary/alternative formulation
I have been exploring normal families and Montel's theorem and recently I came across this alternative formulation (or corollary?):
Let us suppose that $F$ is a family of meromorphic functions defined on an open subset
$D$. If $z_0\in D$  is such that $F$ is not normal at $z_0$ and $z_0\in U\subseteq D$  , then $$\bigcup_{f\in F} f(U)$$
is dense for any non-empty neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$.
I have some idea of how to prove this using the standard Montel Theorem, but I would like a reference for this result: is there a book that includes this?

I would appreciate some help...
